# Specify font with Dompdf?

Tags: php, css, fonts, dompdf

I have uploaded a small example [here](https://github.com/nowox/test-dompdf). It is composed of 3 files.

I would like to use DOMPDF to render a Laravel view on the server side. I realized the font I am using `Open Sans` is not working so I made a simpler test which shows the same issue.

If you try to call `index.php` wou will get this PDF in which the `Lorem` title is not rendered with `Open Sans`.

[image]

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "nowox/test-dompdf",
    "require": {
        "dompdf/dompdf": "^0.8.3",
        "webfontkit/open-sans": "^1.0"
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;

$options = new Options();
$options->set('defaultFont', 'Open Sans');
$options->set('fontDir', 'vendor/webfontkit/open-sans/fonts');

$dompdf = new Dompdf($options);
$dompdf->loadHtml(file_get_contents('template.html'));


$dompdf->setPaper('A4');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream();
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/webfontkit/open-sans/open-sans.min.css"/>
        <style>
        * {
            font-family: 'Open Sans';
        }
        h1 {
            font-family: 'Open Sans';
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Lorem</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dompdf (up to and including 0.8.3) does not support numeric font weights ([see issue #675](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/675)). You'll have to modify your stylesheet to only use "bold" or "normal" for the font weight.